# QGIS 1.8 not loading after install

Tags: qgis

I have just installed QGIS 1.8 on Windows 7.  Once the install completed and I tried to open QGIS (via the desktop icon) nothing happened.  I had this issue when installing QGIS 1.7.  I was able to get 1.7 to open by using the qgis.bat file, but it is not in the the bin folder in the QGIS 1.8 version.  I began to have this issue after installing OpenGeoSuite 4W.  I thought I uninstalled everything I needed.  I am worried I may need to re-install Windows.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what I can do to get QGIS 1.8 to load and open.

Thanks...

Comment: No need to reinstall Windows.  Did you run the install with Admin rights?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.  The 1.8.0 EXE does not have an option to identify the Admin.  If you are asking if I am signed in with Admin privileges, yes.  I have installed the program on three different computers, and one is having this issue.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in Windows7..I had an osgeo4w qgis dev(1.9) version working in Win7..after i messed it up, i never got it to run again..1.8.0 standalone installer too didn't work..now i am back in 1.7.4 :(

Comment: I am having the same thing.  My issue is that I am testing a plugin that will only work in 1.8.0.  I know the plugin works in 1.8.0 because I have tested it on a different machine, but it won't work in 1.7.x

Comment: What installer are you using? Standalone or OsGeo4W?

Comment: Editing the qgis.bat file as mentioned in this answer resolved my issue.. http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31169/5850

Comment: I used the stand alone installer.  This problem is, there is no qgis.bat file in the bin folder on installation.

Comment: Update...I have installed the OSGeo4W version using the Advanced Settings and have had a similar but different issue.  Now QGIS will not install because of an error stating missing jpeg_osgeo.dll  I have had issues like this with developers and programmers who make sloppy installers and packaging.  I have successfully installed this version on two other computers, I am 100% positive that is it associated to a previous install of OSGeo4W.

Comment: The missing jpeg_osgeo.dll should be in the bin folder. Do you have a running installation on another computer from where you can take the dll manually and put it in the bin folder?

Comment: Yes, I have done this already.  This is why I am scared I will need to reinstall Windows.  It really appears to me that its an uninstall issue with OSGeo4W.  It wasn't until I installed OSGeo4W when I had this issue.  I installed QGIS1.8 on another laptop to make sure I wasn't going crazy and it installed perfectly.

Comment: Has the OSGeo4w installer put the dlls in the wrong folder, or crashed before finishing? Perhaps you should open a ticket for that.

Comment: I have not noticed a crash on the install.  Everything seemes to be in the right place, but I wouldn't know for sure, as there is not a document outlining the heirarchy structure for the install setup and the required .dll etc.

Comment: @RyanGarnett-can you post the contents of your qgis.bat?

Comment: I have now used the Osge4w Installer for Qgis master, and had similar problems with other dlls missing. Copying them manually from the standalone installation of Qgis 1.8.0 to the osgeo4w\bin folder solved the problem. I opened a ticket for the buggy installer: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6292    Just one thing about the missing qgis.bat: You do not have the "hide known extensions" option active in the windows folder options? This would qgis.bat display as "qgis".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and started a thread a month or so ago a month. The suggested answers did not work. There is a problem with the QGIS 1.8 installer for Windows 7.0 that is not being addressed. I wiped the slate clean and installed 1.8, and nothing worked. I then reinstalled 1.7 and it works perfectly. I just did a download and install, and it does not work. But 1.7 does work. It is not my job to debug the 1.8 installer. Accept that there is a problem and fix it!

Comment: since QGIS is open source software, technically it's not anyone's job to fix.... just sayin'

Comment: I have had successful installs with QGIS 1.8 on three computers.  The issue I see is with OSGeo4W.  I am going to whip my computer and reinstall Windows 7 and start over.  Not cool!

Comment: I agree that it is an installer issue. But it worked on my computer (and 1.7.4 still running on the same machine), and several others too. Some dll's are not put in the right place, and the installer does not come to an end (missing qgis.bat).

Comment: Andre I agree 100% with that.  I have two computers where I have 1.73 and 1.8.0 running.  The difference on those two computers is that I did not use OSGeo4W as the installer.  I have tried to un-install everything from OSGeo4W (refering to all the posts on the forum) but QGIS 1.8.0 will not install properly on one computer, the computer that used OSGeo4W.  Hence, why I am looking to reinstall Windows, to clean the slate.

Comment: Just wiped away the OSGeo4w folder, and reinstalled qgis-dev from osgeo4w. Now 1.7.4, 1.8.0 and master are running here on the same machine. Perhaps uninstalling both versions, deleting osgeo4w, cleaning your registry from all qgis entrys, deleting C:\users\<username>\.qgis could lead to a clean install.

Comment: I have done all of that.  This is why I am thinking I need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I reinstalled Windows and installed QGIS 1.8 from the standalone installer with no issue.  Seems there is something more to the full and complete uninstall of OSGeo4W and QGIS.