# QGIS Desktop 2.2.0 - program does not start

Tags: qgis, installation

I just installed QGIS 2.2 (I download QGIS Standalone InstalleVersion 2.2 (32 bit)).Installation was successful without any errors.

Then I try lunch QGIS Desktop 2.2.0 but the program does not start.

#### **Update**

In postinstall.log I not found any bugs.

I also install  Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86) and clear path ([Why is QGIS not launching?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/why-is-qgis-not-launching))

Comment: What happens if you start the qgis.bat manually? You can try Start/run -> cmd.exe, and navigate to the folder and start qgis.bat by typing it manually. If something goes wrong, you might read an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in Windows and you have no shortcut created during the installation, you can start QGIS Valmiera by running the bellow commands (depending of your installation folder):

```
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\nircmd.exe exec hide C:\OSGeo4W\bin\qgis.bat
```

or

```
c:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe exec hide c:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\qgis.bat
```

Also, you can create a shortcut if you feel comfortable:

[image]

Comment: The 32 bit standalone Version should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\ `, unless you are still on Windows XP. If the shortcut is not created, something went wrong during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your installation was not successful. Unfortunately, the installer does not report all errors to the screen.

On your disk, look out for the `postinstall.log` file in the QGIS Valmiera folder. You can open it with any text editor and look out for error messages.

Sometimes, an error message occurs complaining that the PATH variable exceeds 1024 characters. In that case, you have to clean up the PATH variable to get QGIS running in a normal way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case QGIS 2.2 started when I fired it from **qgis.bat**

Comment: QGIS should always be started with the bat and not the exe. The desktop icon and the start menu entries should call the bat file.