# Starting QGIS after install on windows XP home?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

New to QGIS and installed 2.6.1 on Windows XP desktop home edition. No errors received during install. When I launch QGIS Brighton from Start - Programs the qgis-bin.exe - Entry Point Not Found pops up.

> The procedure entry point xmlSchemaNewDocParserCtxt could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library libxml2.dll.

The same error shows when launching QGIS Browser 2.6.1 as QGIS Desktop 2.6.1.

Comment: Which QGIS install did you use? QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.6.1-1-Setup-x86_64.exe 28-Nov-2014 13:21 (268M) from http://qgis.org/downloads/

Comment: also see related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89823/qgis-desktop-2-2-0-program-does-not-start

Comment: Thanks for link. I searched other threads as well. It was 32 bit version QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.6.1.1-Setup-x86.exe (without the _64). Still on Windows XP Home which is 32 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for all appearances of `libxml2.dll` on your system. It seems that QGIS expects another version than the one that is addressed first by your PATH varaible.

The one in the QGIS Brighton/bin path should be the right one.

On my XP computer, I have versions between 493kB and 1016kB, and QGIS needs the largest one, from 23.07.2013.